# React Native Server: packager/packager.sh: line 11: node: command not found

Tags: react-native, nuclide-editor

I often get this exception trying to start a debugging session on Nuclide.

```
React Native Server: [...]/packager/packager.sh: line 11: node: command not found
```

Where [...] will represent the correct path to the packager

The server will indicate it's running, but it isn't. Running react-native run-ios from the command line will start its own packager session (successfully).

I also sometimes don't get this error message, but in either case, when I run react-native run-ios, a new packager will be started and the Simulator will indicate "Runtime is not ready for debugging" etc. And the error message always shows up when I restart the packager in Nuclide.

On Chrome, debugging works (although with extremely shaky support for debugger stops stopping at the right line, which why I'm trying Nuclide).

I did get it to work a few times. But it seems unreliable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Nuclide did the trick